# OG. More than 1 video on page

Tags: video, facebook-opengraph

How can I add OG markup for more than 1 video, placed on a page? I need an example please.

I had added markup for 1 video but have no idea how to do it for 2 or more.

Answer (score 0):

Just put *video* tags with necessary params as many times as you need.

Example.

Markup like this

```
        <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/movie.swf" />
        <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/movie.swf" />
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />

        <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/movie1.swf" />
        <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/movie1.swf" />
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />

        <meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/movie2.swf" />
        <meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://secure.example.com/movie2.swf" />
        <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

will give you (in [Facebook Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug))
[image]

It's all about arrays (you can dive in the doc [here](http://ogp.me/#array))

> ### Arrays
>
> If a tag can have multiple values, just put multiple versions of
>   the same `<meta>` tag on your page. The first tag
>   (from top to bottom) is given preference during conflicts.
>
> ```
> <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock.jpg" /> 
> <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock2.jpg" />
> ```
>
> Put structured properties after you declare their root tag.
>   Whenever another root element is parsed, that structured property is
>   considered to be done and another one is started.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock.jpg"/>
> <meta property="og:image:width" content="300" /> 
> <meta property="og:image:height" content="300" />  
> <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock2.jpg" />
> <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/rock3.jpg" />
> <meta property="og:image:height" content="1000" />
> ```
>
> means there are 3 images on this page, the first image is
>   `300x300`, the middle one has unspecified dimensions, and
>   the last one is `1000`px tall.