# How to handle multiple video encodings with OpenGraph?

Tags: html5-video, facebook-opengraph

I've got a page that has as its primary content a video, and I'm trying to set up appropriate og:video tags for it.  To keep all the browsers and devices happy, I have both .mp4 and .webm encodings of the video on the server, with video.js set up to deliver the appropriate encoding to the requesting device.

So, the question: Should I have a set of og:video tags for both encodings -- something like:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.example.com/myvideo.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="938" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="528" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" />

<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.example.com/myvideo.webm" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="938" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="528" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/webm" />
```

My belief is that the og:video tag should be pointing to the actual content -- the video file -- so what happens when there are two?

(Note that these two files are different encodings of the same content -- this is not a reposting of [OG. More than 1 video on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493950/og-more-than-1-video-on-page) .)

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing should be correct. This is equivalent to exposing two different videos as per the [Arrays section of the OpenGraph protocol](https://ogp.me/#array):

> If a tag can have multiple values, just put multiple versions of the same  tag on your page. The first tag (from top to bottom) is given preference during conflicts.
> ...
> Put structured properties after you declare their root tag. Whenever another root element is parsed, that structured property is considered to be done and another one is started.

I would take this to mean an unsupported video format would count as a conflict.